# Issues in X509 implementation using CXF WS in JBOSS 7

Tags: java, jax-ws, cxf, jboss7.x, x509certificate

I have created a WS in CXF using JBOSS and my requirement is that I want to enable X509 
certificate and call WS using CXF client. I am able to created WS and able to call it with
client successfully but when i implement X509 i am getting error :- "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl from [Module "deployment.cxfpoc.war:main" from Service Module Loader]" , below are the details for the same.

My Enviromnet:

Application Server: JBOSS-AS7.1.1.Final
JAVA: 1.7

For X509 implementation i m following below steps:

1) Generate Private Key with testUser/testPass in keystore

keytool -genkey -alias testUser -keypass testPass -keystore privatestore.jks 
-storepass changeit -dname "cn=testUser" -keyalg RSA

2)Self sign certificate

keytool -selfcert -alias testUser -keystore privatestore.jks -storepass changeit -keypass testPass

3)

keytool -export -alias testUser -file key.rsa -keystore privatestore.jks -storepass changeit

4) Generate Public Key Store

keytool -import -alias testUser  -file key.rsa -keystore publicstore.jks -storepass changeit

Now i have copied the publicstore.jks file in WEB-INF/classes folder in Server and also copied
server.properties file:

### server.properties

```
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider=org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type=jks
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password=changeit
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.file=publicstore.jks
```

Now below is the code for Web Service:

### Server Source for Web services

```
package ws;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebResult;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Endpoint;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl;
import org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor;
import org.apache.ws.security.handler.WSHandlerConstants;

@WebService(name = "DemoCXF", serviceName = "DemoCXFService", portName = "DemoCXFPort", targetNamespace = "http://test.org")
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
public class DemoCXF {

    @WebMethod()
    @WebResult(targetNamespace = "http://test.org", name = "updatedEmployee")
    public Employee processEmployeeSalary(
        @WebParam(partName = "employee", name = "employee", targetNamespace = "http://test.org") 
        Employee emp,
        @WebParam(partName = "incrementAmount", name = "incrementAmount", targetNamespace = "http://test.org")
        Long incrementAmount) {
        Map<String,Object> inProps= new HashMap<String,Object>();
        inProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, "Signature");
        inProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIG_PROP_FILE, "server.properties");

        EndpointImpl jaxWsEndpoint = (EndpointImpl) EndpointImpl.publish(WSDL_URL, new DemoCXF());

        Endpoint cxfEndpoint = jaxWsEndpoint.getServer().getEndpoint();

        WSS4JInInterceptor wssIn = new WSS4JInInterceptor(inProps);
        cxfEndpoint.getInInterceptors().add(wssIn);

        System.out.println("[DemoCXF] Method Invoked....processEmployeeSalary");

        System.out.println("[DemoCXF] Before processing: " + emp);

        long incrementedSalary = emp.getEmpSalary() + incrementAmount;

        emp.setEmpSalary(incrementedSalary);

        System.out.println("[DemoCXF] After processing: " + emp);

        return emp;
    }
}
```

### WS is accessible using URL: cxfpoc?wsdl

Now for cilent part I am using below property file and privatestore.jks

### client_sign.properties

```
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider=org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type=jks
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password=changeit
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.alias=testUser
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.file=privatestore.jks
```

I have put below JAR's in classpath for Client : -

```
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
DemoCXFClient.jar [ Generated Client ] 
neethi-3.0.1.jar
wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar
wss4j-1.6.5.jar
xmlschema-core-2.0.jar
xmlsec-1.5.1.jar
and CFX jars from jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules\org\apache\cxf\main folder
```

### Client Code

TestCXF.java

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider;
import org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client;
import org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy;
import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor;
import org.apache.ws.security.WSConstants;
import org.apache.ws.security.handler.WSHandlerConstants;

import client.DemoCXF;
import client.DemoCXFService;
import client.Employee;

public class TestCXF {

    public static void main(String ar[]) throws Exception {
        String WSDL_URL= arr[0] + "/cxfpoc?wsdl";
        DemoCXFService service=new DemoCXFService(new URL(WSDL_URL));
        DemoCXF port=service.getDemoCXFPort();

        Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
        client.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
        client.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());

        Map<String,Object> outProps = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.MUST_UNDERSTAND, "0");
        outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, "Signature");
        outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.USER, "testUser");
        outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PW_CALLBACK_CLASS, KeystorePasswordCallback.class.getName());

        outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIG_PROP_FILE, "client_sign.properties");
        WSS4JOutInterceptor wssOut = new WSS4JOutInterceptor(outProps);

        org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Endpoint cxfEndpoint = client.getEndpoint();

        cxfEndpoint.getOutInterceptors().add(wssOut);

        Employee emp=new Employee();
        emp.setEmpNo(1000L);
        emp.setEmpName("MiddlewaremagicEmployee");
        emp.setEmpSalary(6000L);

        System.out.println("\n\nBefore  EmpNo: "+emp.getEmpNo()+",  Name:"+emp.getEmpName()+",  Sal:"+emp.getEmpSalary());
        emp=port.processEmployeeSalary(emp,1000L);
        System.out.println("\n\nAfter   EmpNo: "+emp.getEmpNo()+",  Name:"+emp.getEmpName()+",  Sal:"+emp.getEmpSalary());
    }
}
```

KeystorePasswordCallback.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.security.auth.callback.Callback;
import javax.security.auth.callback.CallbackHandler;
import javax.security.auth.callback.UnsupportedCallbackException;
import org.apache.ws.security.WSPasswordCallback;

public class KeystorePasswordCallback implements CallbackHandler {
    private Map<String, String> passwords = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public KeystorePasswordCallback() {
        passwords.put("testUser", "testPass");
    }

    public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException, UnsupportedCallbackException {
        for (int i = 0; i < callbacks.length; i++) {
            WSPasswordCallback pc = (WSPasswordCallback)callbacks[i];

            if (pc.getIdentifier().equals("testUser")) {
                // set the password on the callback. This will be compared to the
                // password which was sent from the client.
                pc.setPassword("testPass");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add an alias/password pair to the callback mechanism.
     */
    public void setAliasPassword(String alias, String password) {
        passwords.put(alias, password);
    }
}
```

When i Run client program I am getting below Exception:

```
20:11:49,296 ERROR [org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.InvocationHandlerJAXWS] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-2) Method invocation failed with exception: null: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.AbstractInvocationHandlerJSE.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandlerJSE.java:111)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker._invokeInternal(JBossWSInvoker.java:181)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker.invoke(JBossWSInvoker.java:127)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:207)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:91)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.transport.ServletHelper.callRequestHandler(ServletHelper.java:169)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.invoke(CXFServletExt.java:87)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:185)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:108)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.service(CXFServletExt.java:135)
    at org.jboss.wsf.spi.deployment.WSFServlet.service(WSFServlet.java:140) [jbossws-spi-2.0.3.GA.jar:2.0.3.GA]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cxf/jaxws/EndpointImpl
    at ws.DemoCXF.processEmployeeSalary(DemoCXF.java:37) [classes:]
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl from [Module "deployment.cxfpoc.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    ... 39 more

20:11:49,359 WARNING [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-2) Application {http://test.org}DemoCXFService#{http://test.org}processEmployeeSalary has thrown exception, unwinding now: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: org/apache/cxf/jaxws/EndpointImpl
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker.createFault(JBossWSInvoker.java:246)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker._invokeInternal(JBossWSInvoker.java:201)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker.invoke(JBossWSInvoker.java:127)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:207)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:91)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.transport.ServletHelper.callRequestHandler(ServletHelper.java:169)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.invoke(CXFServletExt.java:87)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:185)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:108)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.service(CXFServletExt.java:135)
    at org.jboss.wsf.spi.deployment.WSFServlet.service(WSFServlet.java:140) [jbossws-spi-2.0.3.GA.jar:2.0.3.GA]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
```

Thanks to suggest how can i solve this issue, I am stuck in this since 3 days. Any help is deeply appreciated.

--- 05 May 2013
---Using below code for server works well and WS get called without any error, but interceptors are not working in that case, means no security is verified.. let me know
how can i fix this.

```
package ws;



import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebResult;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;

import org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client;
import org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Endpoint;
import org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy;
import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl;
import org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor;
import org.apache.ws.security.handler.WSHandlerConstants;

@WebService(name = "DemoCXF", serviceName = "DemoCXFService", portName = "DemoCXFPort", targetNamespace = "http://test.org")
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
public class DemoCXF  implements DemoCXFI{
@WebMethod()
@WebResult(targetNamespace = "http://test.org", name = "updatedEmployee")
public Employee processEmployeeSalary(
        @WebParam(partName = "employee", name = "employee", targetNamespace = "http://test.org") Employee emp,
        @WebParam(partName = "incrementAmount", name = "incrementAmount", targetNamespace = "http://test.org") Long incrementAmount) {

    Map<String, Object> inProps = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    inProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, "Signature");
    inProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIG_PROP_FILE, "server.properties");
    inProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PW_CALLBACK_CLASS, KeystorePasswordCallback.class.getName());
    WSS4JInInterceptor wssIn = new WSS4JInInterceptor(inProps);


    System.out.println("[DemoCXF] Method STEP1");

    // Endpoint cxfEndpoint = null;
    try {


        //EndpointImpl jaxWsEndpoint = (EndpointImpl)
            //    EndpointImpl.publish("http://localhost:8080/cxfpoc?wsdl",DemoCXFI.class);

        Service cxfService = Service.create(new URL(
                "http://localhost:8080/cxfpoc?wsdl"), new QName(
                        "http://test.org", "DemoCXFService"));

        DemoCXFI mySer = cxfService.getPort(DemoCXFI.class); 

        Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(mySer); 

        client.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
        client.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());


        Endpoint cxfEndpoint = client.getEndpoint();

        System.out.println("[DemoCXF] Method STEP2");

    //   Endpoint cxfEndpoint = jaxWsEndpoint.getServer().getEndpoint();

        System.out.println("[DemoCXF] Method STEP3");



        System.out.println("[DemoCXF] Method STEP4");

        cxfEndpoint.getInInterceptors().add(wssIn);

        cxfEndpoint.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
        cxfEndpoint.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());



        System.out
        .println("[DemoCXF] Method Invoked....processEmployeeSalary");

        System.out.println("[DemoCXF] Before processing: " + emp);

        long incrementedSalary = emp.getEmpSalary() + incrementAmount;

        emp.setEmpSalary(incrementedSalary);

        System.out.println("[DemoCXF] After processing: " + emp);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Below line is having error//

    /*
     * EndpointImpl jaxWsEndpoint = (EndpointImpl)
     * EndpointImpl.publish("http://localhost:8085/cxfpoc", new DemoCXF());
     */

    // Some Business Logic to Store the Employee's Updated Details in
    // Database or Messaging System.

    return emp;
}
```

}

Comment: You need to have cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws*.jar on classpath. The Jboss CXF jars contains that first one?

Comment: I have copied the jar in WEB-INF/lib of server (where web service is deployed) still below issue is coming   20:55:08,053  20:55:27,412 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Failed to define class org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl in Module "deployment.cxfpoc.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/apache/cxf/jaxws/EndpointImpl

Comment: I am still struggling with this issue, every time it says class not found, then i search jar from findjar.com corresponding to that class , i have done that 15/20 times but all in vain.. can anyone help plz.

Comment: After adding below lines in MANIFEST.MF the error is fixed , but new errors are coming .. Manifest-Version: 1.0
Dependencies: org.apache.cxf,org.apache.commons.lang

Comment: Using code snippet atached at last for server works well and WS get called without any error, but interceptors are not working in that case, means no security is verified.. let me know how can i fix this.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the JBossWS documentation on running Apache CXF based endpoints on top of JBoss AS 7 / WildFly 8: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/JBWS/WS-Security . Also check the rest of the documentation there for better understanding the Apache CXF integration on JBoss.

Comment: I referred this doc , but as a non spring user, I want to do it via JAVA program/ Annotations iteslf and there is no such stuff avaliable.